# go: field definition with a part other than name, type

Tags: go

I see a struct definition like this:

```
type Resource struct {
    Attrs []Attribute `parquet:",list"`
    ServiceName      string  `parquet:",snappy,dict"`
    Cluster          *string `parquet:",snappy,optional,dict"`
    ....
}
```

I understand first 2 parts of field definition(name, type). But what does that last part mean? Like

`parquet:",snappy,dict"`

Comment: Those are tags, annotations for structure fields that can be accessed through reflection: https://go.dev/ref/spec#Struct_types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text within backquotes describes Go *struct tags* which can be accessed via reflection (see [`reflect.StructTag`](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#StructTag) for details).

These tags are typically used by code that marshals/unmarhals into different formats - often describing how a field should be decoded or encoded. The use of struct tags for `encoding/json` is fairly well documented for the [`Marshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshal) and [`Unmarshal`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshal) functions.

Your example appears to be related to the [`github.com/segmentio/parquet-go`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/parquet-go) package. It has some brief [documentation on how the package interprets struct tags](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/segmentio/parquet-go#SchemaOf).

In particular:

- `snappy` encodes the column with Snappy compression
- `dict` enables Dict encoding with the [Parquet file](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet).
- `optional` indicates the Parquet column is optional.
- `list` indicates the the parquet LIST logical type should be used.